# Python - Need help to understand how to call a function

Tags: python, function

I am new to programming, and trying out with a little Python3.

I have some trouble understanding the concept behind calling a function? having the defined the following function, what would be the proper way to call it?

```
def string_length(mystring):
return len(mystring)
```

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: `string_length('hello')` for example

Comment: first, your spacing is off. the second line needs to be indented 4 spaces. Second, you'd call it by calling it: "print string_length(this_string)"  or "sl = string_length('this')"

Comment: [Start with tutorials to understand concepts.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_functions.htm)

Comment: If you are really new to programming maybe a more basic introduction http://www.programmingbasics.org/en/ if the question was only about the syntax of python, sorry for misinterpreting.

Comment: Note that `len` is itself a function that you are already calling

Comment: You really need to [read the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def string_length(mystring):
    return len(mystring)

print(string_length('something'))
```

Like that

Comment: Thanks mate - what is the purpose of the 'mystring*? that could be anything typed in there, right? by doesn't seem to be used anywhere?

Comment: It's just a variable that's used internally in the function you define. So yes it could be anything you want. If you say `x=5` and then `def some_func(fart)` and the call `some_func(x)`, this tells `some_func` that you want `fart` to be `5` in this case.

Comment: Thanks SuperStew

Answer (score 0):

```
length = string_length('some_string')
```

where `length` is a variable that will store the output.